# Sbt credentials: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: user must not be null

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to add credentials look up to a multi-module project. 
So I've been [following the guidelines to add credentials](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Publishing.html#Credentials). 
I added `credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".sbt" / ".cogcompCredentials"),` to the sbt project common settings (common between modules).  And also added the file `~/.sbt/.cogcompCredentials`:

```
realm=yada yada 
host=url
user=uname
password=pass
```

Upon `publish` it says:

moduleName/*:publish
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: user must not be null

Ironically when I rename the file name to sth random, I still get the same name. I also tried giving the u-pass dirctly by using `credentials += Credentials("yada yada", "url", "uname", "pass"),` and still get the same error.

Any ideas where I might be going wrong? Or how to debug this?

Update: here is the actual change: https://github.com/IllinoisCogComp/saul/pull/373/

Side note: I tested on a MacBook pro, although it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently Ivy credentials are only used for HTTP(s) resolvers (see Ivy docs: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/credentials.html).

While I was using sftp resolver. For this type of resolver [there are other ways to specify the credentials](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Resolvers.html#SFTP+and+SSH+Repositories).